# Filtering Active Directory Users in Alphabetical Order

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I've got to modify a property in active directory for each user throughout the company I work for.  This is the code that I am user to get all users.

```
        String domain = Properties.Settings.Default.ADConn;
        String user = Properties.Settings.Default.ADAdmin;
        String pass = Properties.Settings.Default.ADPass;

        DirectoryEntry ADEntry = new DirectoryEntry(domain, user, pass);
        DirectorySearcher ADSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(ADEntry);
        ADSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";                        
        SearchResultCollection allResults = ADSearcher.FindAll();            
        foreach (SearchResult result in allResults)
        {
            DirectoryEntry deUser = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

             //....Do stuff here
```

There are a large amount of people in the company, and so it was requested that I split the users alphabetically and handle one chunk of users at a time.  For example, change properties for users [A-G], then [H-N], then [O-Z].  How can I modify my filter to give me users X through Y?

**EDIT:** My Final result was to do the following:

```
ADSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName>=X)(sAMAccountName<=Y))";
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To clarify, by "users X through Y" I mean users whose last names or possibly samaccountnames start with X through users whose last names or possibly samaccountnames start with Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used OpenLDAP before so I am little bit familiar with filters and I found a [Search Filter Syntax document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(VS.85).aspx) which might help. Here is what I think might be possible:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(cn>='a')(cn<='b'))
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I believe you need to drop the quotes around the letters.  So a **LastName** search would be:    `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sn>=m)(sn<=p))`  A **username** search would be: `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName>=m)(sAMAccountName<=p))`

Comment: Both of you together are correct.  This worked perfectly.  Thank you very much.